# Why doesn't my Yamaha R3 Motorcycle power on?

Tags: electrical, motorcycle, repair, power, yamaha

My 2017 Yamaha R3 won't power on.
Everything was fine with it initially, I rode it this morning and the ride was perfect.

After a couple of hours in my garage, I turn the ignition key, the electric dash lights up, I push the ignition button, and all of a sudden everything goes dark. The dash does not light up anymore and the ignition button does not work anymore either. I checked all the fuses and they were intact. I changed the main 25A fuse to the spare (just for a test) and the screen lit up for a second before going dark again. The battery is fine too when I checked it. Not sure what to do from here solution wise.

Please Help!!

Answer (score 2):

Does the starter engage and crank at all ?  It feels like the battery is weak, and when you try and engage the starter  the power draw is too high for what the battery can supply.

When you checked the battery, how did you do that?  Just measuring the voltage is a good start, but it isn't the whole picture of battery health.

If this bike has a kickstarter, try that and see if it starts.  Seems to be lacking on many modern bikes, which is a shame.

Either try a fresh battery, or take the existing battery for a deeper health checkup.  If its the original battery then its 5 years old now, and could be at End of Service.

Comment: Ended up being the battery! Replaced it and it was all good to go afterwards. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The same thing happened with my KTM Duke 250. On a winter morning, my bike won't start and after trying too many times the instrument panel went dark. But before shutting off my instrument console showed an error code. I took my Duke 250 to the service centre and turns out my battery was drained. After replacing the battery, this issue got resolved.

Comment: Yup me too, it was the battery. Once I replaced it, the bike ran fine.